# No difference in output running 'cut -f 1 sample.txt'

Tags: cut

```
echo 'The quick brown; fox jumps over the lazy dog' > sample.txt
```

I then run

```
cut -f 1 sample.txt
```

or

```
cut -f 2 sample.txt
```

and my output is always the same,

```
The quick brown; fox jumps; over the lazy dog;
```

should't the output of the first 'cut' command be 'dog'? Why is the output the same if I run each 'cut' command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default separator is tab, if you want space instead set it with -d (delimeter)

```
cut -f 1 -d ' ' sample.txt
The
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cut